# Increase timer resolution (high resolution) on Windows without NtSetTimerResolution

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, timer

I'm looking for some kind of timer that has a higher resolution than the Windows default of ~15ms. I don't need a timer for time measurement but rather a timer that is able to wait X milliseconds (or call an event every X milliseconds). I know it's possible to change the Windows timer resolution with `NtSetTimerResolution`, but that affects all applications (which I don't want). I don't need much precision, so say if I'm looking for 2ms then 1.5ms and 2.5ms would be OK too.

Using spinners work but this obviously causes too much CPU usage. Ideas that are creative are welcome too, as long as it can get the job done.

Comment: Have you tried std::chrono?

Comment: [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Comment: which is the problem affecting every application?
it does not affect timer durations themselves, just the minimum resolution.

Comment: Please choose a language, the answer for `c++` and `c#` are very different.

Comment: @Federico I need to run check something about every 2ms, the normal Windows timer doesn't allow that resolution (~15.6ms). You can change the timer resolution with NtSetTimerResolution but that has the drawback that all system timers change their resolution.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have C++ and C# both because they're both fine for me, only requirement is that it should support Windows.

Comment: std::chrono seems to be only for getting the current time, I need a timer that gives an event every x ms (or can wait for x ms).

Comment: [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod),

Comment: https://gha.st/short-sleeps/

Comment: @JeffreyShao-MSFT that's also system wide.

Comment: Yes, I mean call this function before using timer services, and call the `timeEndPeriod` after you are finished services. But it seems that your service works long time.

Comment: Correct, it's a permanent check running as a Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

`NtSetTimerResolution` and `timeBeginPeriod` can increase timer resoultion, but they are system wide. If anyone has good idea, please tell me.

I don't recommend that you do this. Google has modified Chrome to increase the timer frequency only when necessary, which works in most cases.

The default timer resolution on Windows is 15.6 ms – the timer interrupts 64 times per second. As the program increases the timer frequency, they increase power consumption and impair battery life. They also waste more computing power than I expected – they slow down your computer! Because of these problems, Microsoft has been telling developers for years not to increase the timer frequency.